# What is the most likely reaction between minocycline and tramadol in physiological conditions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, chemical-biology, drugs

[Minocyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minocycline) (left) and [Tramadol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tramadol) (right) are two commonly prescribed medications containing typical organic functional groups.

What would an expert chemist surmise as the first or most-likely reaction involving these drugs in the human body, if any? For example, in the stomach, in a highly acidic environment?

I realize the chemistry here is obviously complex, so an answer excluding biological components is fine. e.g. what would these compounds do in a solution of $\ce{HCl}$ alone?

I'm not an organic chemist, but my guess is that $\ce{HCl}$ can protonate an amine to encourage some kind of reaction.

In any case, some research has shown that the drugs may have a synergistic effect for pain relief: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22964800.

[image: Minocyline]
[image: Tramadol]

Comment: You're looking for reactions _between_ these two substances under physiological conditions? Or do you just want to know how they are individually metabolized?

Comment: Reactions between.

Comment: I would expect that you'd protonate the nitrogens and for ammonium ions. They don't quite have the best functional groups for cross reactivity...

Comment: There's no reaction. If there was it would be used purposefully, or dangerous.